Init Script on databricks
Life of the Init script from DBFS has come to an end. I used to deploy the databricks cluster using this powershell script with InitScript paramter.
New-DatabricksCluster -BearerToken $ADB_Token -Region $region -ClusterName $cname -SparkVersion $csparkV `
-NodeType $cnodeT -MinNumberOfWorkers $cminWorker -MaxNumberOfWorkers $cmaxWorker -AutoTerminationMinutes $cterm `
-InitScripts "/Init/pyodbc.sh" -UniqueNames -Update

But oficial documentation of this powershell function states that it must but DBFS path.

.PARAMETER InitScripts Init scripts to run post creation. As array of
strings - paths must be full dbfs paths. Example:
"dbfs:/script/script1", "dbfs:/script/script2"

Now I want to migrate from DBFS to Workspace file location, while I can achieve this via databricks UI, i was wondering how can I do the same thing with the powershell code or even databricks API.

Unfortunately the module you are using doesn't give the option to set workspace type init script.
So, try below module.

Installing

Install-Module -Name DatabricksPS


Next, set the environment.

$accessToken = "dapi12345sxsdksancldkcna7c51"
$apiUrl = "https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net"

Set-DatabricksEnvironment -AccessToken $accessToken -ApiRootUrl $apiUrl


Create cluster with below commands.

$init_scripts = @( @{ "workspace" = @{ "destination" = "/Users/<user_id>/init.sh"; }; } )
Add-DatabricksCluster -NumWorkers 2 -ClusterName "MyCluster" -SparkVersion "4.0.x-scala2.11" -NodeTypeId 'Standard_DS3_v2'  -InitScripts $init_scripts

Output:

and in portal

refer more about this module here.

While this helps alot and is the right solution, before this activity I need to place the initscript file in the workspace and Im also strugling with it. I tried to use the module you proposed but seems to not working. I have my original question here if you dont mind to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78692837/import-files-to-databricks-workspace
